# WordPress: Switch taxonomy entries between taxonomies

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have to migrate a WP site to another server but the custom taxonomies need to be moved around:

### OLD taxonomy tree:

```
Post -> Topic (taxonomy)
            - Arts
            - Science
            - Politics

     -> Theme (taxonomy)
            - Insights
            - Ideas
            - Philosophy
```

### NEW taxonomy tree:

```
Post -> Topic (taxonomy)
            - Arts
            - Ideas
            - Politics

     -> Theme (taxonomy)
            - Insights
            - Science
            - Philosophy
```

You'll notice the custom taxonomy items Science <=> Ideas have switched from one taxonomy to another. There are about 600 posts that have already taxonomies attached and I was wondering if there's a non-manual way to do this.

It would basically be to move a taxonomy entry to another taxonomy. Is this possible?

Comment: I just realized I should've posted this in the Webmasters Community. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plugin such as [Taxonomy Switcher](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-switcher/screenshots/) should be able to do this.

Comment: PERFECT! Exactly what I was looking for. And easy to use too. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help! Can you mark this answer as correct? Thanks!